# Determining if Pandas column containing array includes specific values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that contains three columns: two define the start and end of a period of time (a window) and another which contains an array of individual timepoints. I would like to determine if any of the individual points are within the window's start and end (the two other columns). The ideal output would be True/False for each row.

I can iterate through each row of the dataframe, extract the timepoints and start_window and end_window times and determine this one row at a time, but I was looking for a faster (no-loop) option.

Example of dataframe

```
row    start_window     end_window        times (numpy array)

0      307.110309       307.710309     [307.48857, 307.6031]
1      309.140340       311.900309     [315.23134]
```

...

The output based on the above dataframe would be:

True

False

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is use `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: any(x['start_window']< i< x['end_window'] for i in x['times']), 1)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us do it vertorized

```
s=pd.DataFrame(df.time.tolist(),index=df.index)
((df.start_window-s<0)&(df.end_window-s>0)).any(1)
Out[277]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another efficient solution.

```
t_max = df["times"].apply(max)
t_min = df["times"].apply(min)
out = (t_max > df["start_window"]) & (t_min < df["end_window"])
```